# Firefox putting gap/margin under my flash header...anyone know a fix?

Tags: css, flash, firefox, margin

it Hi, so I have a flash header on my site - nothing crazy, just a short clip. It works in safari and opera on the mac and all IE versions on PC. It will not work properly on firefox on either PC or Mac. Firefox seems to be putting a gap of 10-20px under the flash, and it looks stupid :(

I have looked up many fixes for this as it seems to be a known problem. I have seen people say it's because the "object" element it treated like letters in FF, so it allows room for the "tails" on a G and Y etc (not sure if I explained that well enough, hopefully you get the idea). I have tried margin:0;  padding:0; line-height:0; font-size:0; float:left; vertical-align:middle; and clear;both;  - not at the same time, I have tried many combinations and got most of these ideas from other threads/articles where people had found a solution. I have tried this CSS on an id attached to the object, on the element object and on the parent div - I just can't seem to fix it!

Also, as a side note - I've noticed the flash looks good in IE6, IE7 but IE8 makes it looks awful - can anyone explain why or confirm that is what they see? Im a mac user so borrow a laptop to test, it would be good to hear if anyone else see's this problem.

[Here is my site](http://www.ransomedesign.co.uk)

Thanks for any help you can provide, i'd like to sort real soon, I have been looking for an answer for hours now. I have also tried the swfobject thing which was recommended to me - works better in other ways but doesn't help this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the margin bottom on #nav to padding bottom. You might then need to tweak your styling a bit

Comment: Hi, I just changed the CSS as you said - it puts my underline background under the nav off but gets rid of the gap! How the HELL does that work? What's margin bottom on an element below got to do with the flash above it? While your at it, do you know why im having so many issues with the background images on my nav in ie8?

Comment: Just got in from work and it all seems to be fixed on FF. Figured it out in the end? I don't have IE8 available here, what exactly are the issues?

Comment: Hi, yes your margin fix worked, it seems really crazy after spending so long looking for an answer that's all it would be. The other issues (i'm not proud of this!) came from testing on a windows laptop I borrow every now and again. I have an imac and macbook so I don't use windows at all anymore. The resolution is different on the screen so most sites look very different...after three hours of changing CSS for IE8 I saw in the bottom right hand corner 90% - I couldn't believe it, it was the settings for viewing messing it up! A mac renders it right, clearly windows doesn't! So silly of me!

Comment: I also wanted to say thank you very much for the help - it's genuinely appreciated.